# Show message during lengthy operation?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a small bit of code that takes about a minute or so to complete.  In that time, there is no indication that anything is happening.  Once the work is completed, a message is displayed in a label.text on the form.  Here's the code:

```
private void UpdateLesson()
{
    var bridgeBll = new BridgeBll();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        bridgeBll.UpdateLesson(row);
    }
    lblMessage.Text = "Saved at " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
}
```

What I'd like to do is display a messagebox that says something like "Saving..." and then have that messagebox close once the operation is complete.  The problem is, though, that if I open a message box, the work won't start until the user manually closes the messagebox and the program continues.

How could I go about doing something like this?

Comment: Use a progress bar. You can either use the number of rows to show the % complete, or just use a marque bar.

Comment: A progress bar is also more reassuring to a user - particularly here where you can easily show an estimated % complete - as it communicates that something is _still happening_ rather than the user just having to wait for a message box to disappear.

Comment: I also suggest changing the cursor to a wait cursor, e.g. `Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.WaitCursor`.

Comment: Using a progress bar does sound like something I should use.  Looks like I'll be needing to brush up on progress bar controls and background workers.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put btnStart Button and label1 Label on your form and use following code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    MyAsyncClass worker;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = string.Format("Worker Started at {0}", DateTime.Now);
        if (worker == null)
        {
            worker = new MyAsyncClass();
            worker.NotifyCompleteEvent += worker_NotifyCompleteEvent;
        }
        worker.Start();
    }

    void worker_NotifyCompleteEvent(string message)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Worker completed with message: {0}", message));
    }

}
```

And here is worker class:

```
public class MyAsyncClass
{

    public delegate void NotifyComplete(string message);
    public event NotifyComplete NotifyCompleteEvent;

    public void Start()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(DoSomeJob));
        t.Start();
    }

    void DoSomeJob()
    {
        //just wait 5 sec for nothing special...
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        if (NotifyCompleteEvent != null)
        {
            NotifyCompleteEvent("My job is completed!");
        }
    }
}
```

You can use this principle also without user interface. Happy coding!